# newrelic agent is not sending data to newrelic servers at staging only

Tags: python, flask, newrelic

I have a new relic agent configured like so:

`newrelic==2.56.0.42`

```
    newrelic.agent.initialize(newrelic_ini_file, newrelic_env)
    logging.info('NewRelic initialized with newrelic_env '+repr(newrelic_env))
    logging.info('NewRelic config name is '+repr(newrelic.agent.application().name))
```

It's logging the "right" things in `staging`, but it's not sending.

```
 NewRelic initialized with newrelic_env 'staging'
 NewRelic config name is 'My Service (Staging)'
```

The agents send data from `localhost` and `production`.

This is some configs from the `newrelic.ini` file

```
[newrelic]
license_key = xxxxx
app_name = My Service
monitor_mode = true
log_file = /tmp/newrelic-python-agent.log
log_level = info
```

This is my staging config in `newrelic.ini`

```
[newrelic:staging]
app_name = My Service (Staging)
monitor_mode = true
log_level = debug
```

One log that I think is *suspicious* is this

```
(14/NR-Harvest-Thread) newrelic.core.agent DEBUG - Completed harvest of all application data in 0.00 seconds.
```

I think the agent not collecting any data due to the `0.00 seconds` part.

What `debug` logs should I look for, for validating actual data being sent and received `200` from new relic.

Additional details:
staging is running on `Docker` `alpine:3.6`

Comment: tried debugging tool of new relic?  https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/troubleshooting/new-relic-diagnostics

Comment: @Shubham I did. all success in all items except for log `Failure  Base/Log/Copy` and no explanation on that error

Comment: Add log_File param in newrelic config and verbose:1 . to get detailed logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue to the answer was indeed the debug log of `harvest of all application data in 0.00 seconds.`

apparently, `newrelic.agent.initialize` has to go **BEFORE** `app = Flask(__name__)`. Moved before and it started sending.

Answer (score 0):

According to [newrelic discuss](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/failure-base-log-copy-log-file-not-found-please-check-working-directory/52234), the `Failure  Base/Log/Copy` can be resolved by configuration change

> You can include this line in your config file, as well, which will stop them from going to the default location:
>
> ```
> log_to_stdout: false
> ```

Another [issue](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/troubleshooting/python-agent-logging) can be that log level should be info

```
log_level = info
```

> Logging at debug can generate a lot of data very quickly. Monitor the size of your log file closely, changing log_level back to info as you finish troubleshooting.

**EDIT**

Issue was asked in [newrelic discuss](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/newrelic-python-agent-is-not-sending-data-to-newrelic-servers-at-staging-only/58020).

Comment: 1. I don't think this `Failure` is related to newrlic reporting since it's in staging env only. 2. `log_to_stdout: false` didn't solve the `Failure Base/Log/Copy` error

Comment: @WebQube do you have different license_key in stage?

Comment: It used to be info and still didn't work. updated my questions with configs in the general section (not specific to `staging`)

Comment: @WebQube can you add `–enable-threads` ? see http://ianozsvald.com/2014/12/10/new-relic-uwsgi-and-cannot-perform-a-data-harvest-for-as-there-is-no-active-session/

Comment: last resort, see NewRelic answer with similar issue https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/python-cant-send-custom-metric-do-newrelic/53003

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177555/discussion-between-webqube-and-user7294900).